# How Do I Find the Script SRC in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am REALLY new to Jasmine and am trying to write a unit test that checks if a URL is constructed properly from variables defined by the environment.

```
describe('URL is built properly', function() {
        var newHead = '<!doctype html>' +
            '<html class="no-js" lang="">' +
            '    <head>' +
            '    </head>' +
            '<body>' +
            '</body>' +
            '</html>';

        beforeEach(function() {
            ScratchPad.clear();
            ScratchPad.add(newHead);
            debugger;
            spyOn(newSetup.prototype, 'createNewScript');
        });
        afterAll(function() {
            ScratchPad.clear();
        });

        it('should build Staging', function() {
            window.my.env = 'staging';
            window.my = {
                newScript: {
                    enabled: true,
                    location: 'google-com'
                }
            };

            var options = {
                windowWidth: 640
            };

            this.newScript = new newScriptSetup(options);
            var newHTML = ScratchPad.find('script')[0].src;
            debugger;
            expect(newHTML.src).toEqual('http://my.site.com/google-com/myScript.min.js');
        });
    });
```

The problem I seem to be having is that;

```
expect(newHTML.src).toEqual('http://my.site.com/google-com/myScript.min.js');
```

this bit of the script isn't getting populated, I've tried debugging it and the var newHead is being created, it's just not being seen by the rest of the unit test... I think. Could someone help me out, I've been looking at it all day :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newHTML = ScratchPad.find('script')[0].src;
debugger;
expect(newHTML.src)..
```

You are already getting the `src` in newHTML. You are trying to check .src.src with the url you provide. Try this:

```
var newHTML = ScratchPad.find('script')[0].src;
expect(newHTML).toBe(..
```